# Ext JS: Override JsonReader or post-process

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonstore, jsonreader

A particular request to my server returns x fields of JSON.  I want to combine several of these fields and insert the concatenated data into the x+1 field of my JsonStore.

I know how to process the load event, read each record, concatenate the appropriate fields, and insert into my x+1st field.  However, is there a better (more efficient) way to accomplish this - perhaps by overriding JsonReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `Ext.data.Field.convert`

Reference - [ExtJS 3.x](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.Field) / [ExtJS 4.x](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Field)

Example using 4.x version -

```
....
fields: [
        'name', 'email',
        {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'gender', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Unknown'},

        {
            name: 'whatever',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.get('f1') + record.get('a2'),
            }
        }
    ]
....
```

Comment: You are correct - this is exactly what I want (+1).  However, my convert function is never called.  I am using my store with a SuperBoxSelect - maybe that UX somehow halts the call to convert???

Comment: @upper stage - post some code. technically, if the store is being loaded with records, convert should be called since this is supposed to be called at record creation time. I am not familiar with SuperBoxSelect